# Dissecting trapezoids into triangles of equal area

Tags: geometry, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, open-problems

[Lightly edited for copy and proper formatting of mathematics. -- Pete L. Clark]

The Background: Let $T$ be a trapezoid. Sherman Stein, using valuation theory, showed that if  $T$ is dissectible into n triangles of equal area, then $\frac{n}{(r+1)}$, where $r$ is the ratio of the parallel sides, is an algebraic integer.  See

> Monsky and Jepsen, *Constructing equidissections for certain classes of trapezoids*, Discrete Mathematics,
>   308 23 (2008) 5672-5681.

In particular $r$ is algebraic.

If $r$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$, a diagonal of $T$ divides $T$ into two triangles of commensurable area, so $T$ has an
"equidissection". Stein showed that if $r$ is a root of a degree $2$ element of $\mathbb{Q}[z]$ [i.e., the univariate polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Q}$ -- PLC] with both
roots positive, then $T$ is equidissectible. Using ideas of Stein and Jepsen I showed that if $r$ is a
root of a degree $3$ or $4$ element of $\mathbb{Q}[z]$ with all roots in the open right half-plane, then once more $T$ is equidissectible. (It's not clear that my proof can be adapted to degree greater than $4$).
In contrast, whenever the algebraic $r$ has a conjugate over $\mathbb{Q}$ that's not in the open right half-plane, nothing is known about the equidissectibilty of $T$. Stein conjectured that when $r$ has a $\mathbb{Q}$-conjugate not in this half plane, then $T$ is not equidissectible. I ask:

The Question: Is it true that if $r$ has a $\mathbb{Q}$-conjugate not in the open right half-plane then $T$ cannot be dissected into triangles of equal area? (For no such $r$ has an equidissection of $T$ or a proof of non-equidissectibility been found).

Comment: Is this an open problem? If so, it should have an "open problem" tag.

Comment: Prof. Monsky is the founder of this subject area: see http://www.math.uga.edu/~pete/Monsky.pdf.  So, yes, if he's asking the question, I think we may assume it is an open problem.  

Comment: What is the meaning of the z in Q[z]? It doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. 

Comment: @Gerry: Apparently, the fact that Q isn't defined anywhere is OK by you? :)

Comment: Micro-comment-question: do we need axiom of choice to be able to extend p-adic valuation on rationals to reals?

Comment: @Prof. Monsky: I made some edits which I hope you find helpful.  If you have any objections or concerns, please let me know here or by email.  (Of course, you can also reedit yourelf, but perhaps your commitment to MO is not (yet?) deep enough for that to seem an attractive option.)

Comment: @Dror: yes, extending a non-Archimedean valuation from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ seems to require AC.  (I don't know of a formal proof of this though.)  Note however that for the application at hand, one can get away with extending to a finitely generated field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$-- see the last sentence of Monsky's article in my comment above -- and this requires no choice whatsoever.  

Comment: @Victor, I don't know what I was thinking, but whatever it was, it was nuts. 